# Is it possible to extract many municipalities out of a state map at once?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, query

Is it possible to extract many municipalities out of a state map at once? I mean not to have to do the QUERY for each and one of them?

Comment: How do you want to choose which municipalities to extract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's certainly possible. While you would use something like

```
name = 'mystate'
```

for one state, you can use

```
name IN ('stateA','stateB','stateC')
```

to get multiple ones.